# Principle curvature from torsion over curvature ratio?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

If we have a curve $\gamma$ that is paramterized over its arc length, lets say for example $\gamma ~[a,b] \rightarrow 
 \mathbb{R}^{3}$,  can we obtain the principle curvature of its tangent surface from the  ratio between the torsion the curvature? like for e.g. $$k_{1}(s,v) = \frac{\tau(s)}{k(s)|v|} $$ assuming $v$ is not $0$, and assiming $k_{2}=0$

Comment: What have you tried? See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Comment: Please show your work and ask a specific question where you get stuck. And what do you mean by *the* principal curvature?